# How to approach my boss about a workshop I'd like to attend to knowing that we have a tight budget?

Tags: communication

There's this seminar/workshop that is work related and might help me a lot in developing in future projects with our specific framework.

However, I am quite aware that we are on a tight budget.

Given this, how should I approach my boss about the workshop that I want to attend to? What I'm thinking is I should present a case how this will be beneficial in the long term for our company, although I'm not exactly sure how to present that objectively.

Comment: The only way would be to convince him that it will bring more money than the cost. Since you're targeting lon term ROI on it, this sounds pretty risky...

Comment: There is no company that will tell that they have an open budget, all budgets are forever tight. You should approach it as any other request, highlighting that its appropriate/relevant to your job role.

Comment: Depending how badly you want to go to this workshop, you could offer to cover some of the costs personally. E.g. You cover travel and workshop fees, but still get paid for your time there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring what information you have regarding the workshop and related costs to your boss. Express your interest in attending and what skills you believe will be improved or added by attending. If you are able to tie the workshop/skills to specific upcoming projects on your road map this will help support your request.

I would suggest leading with an email and a request to discuss in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be difficult to breach, even in a company that *has* money to spare, because all business expenses will be treated with scrutiny when you bring them to the manager.

You need to prepare yourself with as much knowledge about the workshop as you can.  Correlate as much of your on-the-job duties as possible to the training that this workshop offers, highlight your own level of skill and the skill that this workshop promises to deliver to you for taking it, and if possible highlight how much added value to your workflow taking this course will bring.

You can, if you're very eager to take this workshop, offer to cover some of the cost yourself, depending on how important it is for your personal growth in your career.

Remember not to be intimidated by an initial opposition - if your group really is on a tight budget, you will have to fight a little to get this approved.  Stand your facts up, and back them up as well as you can.

Also, make sure you present them in the best way possible to your boss - some bosses prefer face-to-face discussions, others prefer email.  So cater your request to the way your boss prefers to be approached.